# Not correct page breaks if print from IE COM interface IWebBrowser

Tags: com, printing, internet-explorer

I have HTML document to print from embedded COM IWebBrowser object.
And although in IE itself it printed with correct page breaks (by page-break-inside in CSS).
In my application it make it wrong.

I'm already dig it much. Can you suggest something?

Comment: its just as I say  
if I print same doc (menu File-Print) in IE -- it prints with page breaks  
if I print it from WebBrowser COM i.e. webBrowser->ExecWB(...) -- it does'nt print breaks  
That's it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your scenario (since it is a bit ambiguous), but I had an IE page being generated by Javascript, using the DOM and found in some cases that Javascript (or IE's DOM) was adding breaks after every append, or some such, where it wasn't supposed to.  I was able to work-around the problem by building my string in memory first, and only sending it where it was needed once the string was completely built.

Comment: its not my case  
I need to print preserved page  
And yet...   where you run your JavaScript? From IE or from WebBrowser interface to it?  
As it seems, its just a nasty bug with IE COM -- in IE itself it was fixed, but in the WebBrowser COM not :(

Comment: My scenario was a Vista Gadget, running javascript on the web page to generate the HTML for a flyout page.  But since the bug may have been from the DOM interface, I thought it was worth suggesting this as a possiblity, even if our scenarios are not identical.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [print templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434(VS.85).aspx) for control your printing flow.

Comment: Yes. I was discovered such possibility  
but it is not an answer
Only If you can give me correct example or code snippet I can insert into my print template to get correct page breaks

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the DOCTYPE.